# IOS-install from App Store over top ad hoc

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, installation, adhoc

I recently experienced an issue with the following scenario:

1). Installed my app on another device through XCode
  2). Fixed some issues and submitted to the App Store
  3). User using the device from step 1 downloaded the app from the store

We noticed they were still running into some issues that were fixed in step 2.

We had them delete the App and download from the store again and the issues did not exist. We did these steps on 2 different devices with the same results.

It could be something that I did, but has anyone else experienced this or could explain the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced confusion with this scenario in the past.

I would recommend that when you do ad hoc builds you should increment the version number before submitting to the app store. If the adhoc is on a device and the build that gets pushed to the store then the user won't get a notification about it and it will be confused. Your scenario may have been solved if the ad hoc you gave to the user was version 1.9 but the store version was 2.0.